# How to copy choice column values to lookup column values

Tags: lookup-column, choice-field

I am using sp 2010. I have a column from type "choice" and is multiple. I have created a new column from type lookup field. Also this lookup column is multiple. I already have migrated the values to the lookup list.

But how to copy the choice column values to the lookup column?

Answer (score 0):

I think open the list (view) and edit the items through Quick View (from ribbon under List tab). It opens the items in a spreadsheet format.

You can copy the choice column value and paste it in lookup column value.
Hopefully this works, though i have not tried with different type columns. It's just a thought.

Comment: Hi Murali, no that is not working. I think because it is a multiple column.